# I have one next button onclick of it increments my url as http://www.dev-crn.com:5703/tag/cloud/6... so on

Tags: jquery

I have one next button onclick of it increments my url as http://www.dev-crn.com:5703/tag/cloud/6... so on
now i need to decrement the url onclick of previous button how can i achieve that

```js
<#assign nextUrl = "/tag/"+model.data.tag+"/"+(model.page+1) />
<div class="load-more">
<a href="${nextUrl}" class="btn-on-white white">Next</a>
</div>
```

the above code works for incrementing the url number how can i decrement using the same?